# ActiveRecord. Include data from join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

(Ruby/Rails guru's preferably :P)

I've got a bit of an interesting question. Hope it's not already answered (wait, yes I do!) but I've looked and couldn't find it. (Hopefully not because it's not possible)

I've got two classes (and I'd like to keep it that way) Group and Event (see below).

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end
```

However in my join table (group_events), I have additional columns which provide extenuating circumstances to the event... I want this information to be available on the event object. (For example, whether attendance is mandatory or not etc)

My second slightly related question is, can I not do the following:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class GroupEvent < Event
    # Implies that a GroupEvent would be an Event, with all the other attributes of the group_events table minus the
    # two id's (group_id, event_id) that allowed for its existence (those would just be references to the group and event object)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first rewrite the `has_and_belongs_to_many`, explicitly describing the relationship between `Event` and the model for `GroupEvent`.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_events
  has_many :events, :through => :group_events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_events
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_events
end

class GroupEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :event
end
```

You can then methods within the `Event` class to refer to the GroupEvent attributes your'e after. For some boolean `:attendance_mandatory` attribute in `GroupEvent`, you could do something like

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_events
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_events

  def attendance_mandatory?(group)
    group_events.find(group.id).attendance_mandatory?
  end
end
```

With some `Event` as `e` and associated `Group` as `g`, you could now do

```
e.attentdance_mandatory?(g)
```

As for your 2nd question, I think you're looking for a piece of what I've posted in the first code block above.

```
class GroupEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Every table containing data you wish to interact with should have a representative model in your application. The above meets your stated criteria *(exposes the attributes of a `GroupEvent`)*.

**Note:** Your syntax of `class GroupEvent < Event` is used for [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) *(you'd move the attributes like `attendance_mandatory` into the `events` table, and use that `events` table for both a regular `Event` and a `GroupEvent` - though this is outside of the scope of this question)*

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've learned a lot since that question, I appreciate your feedback. I'm using views to help out, but exposing the joining model like you suggested is the way to go.